# PHP Arrays and how to get an array from an object

Tags: php, arrays, json

hoping someone here might be able to advise on what the syntax should be to get the data in the transactions array within the data object below

```
{
  "data": {
       "pages":10,
       "current":1,
       "token":"1234-1234-1234-1234",
       "transactions":[{"id"}]
   }
}
```

im trying to output the data

```
    <?php foreach ($someArray as $key => $value){
    echo "<tr><td>". $value[columns][tranid];
    echo "</td><td>". $value[recordtype];
    echo "</td><td>". $value[columns][trandate];
    echo "</td><td>". $value[columns][poref];
    echo "</td><td>". $value[columns][ref][name];
    echo "</td><td>$". number_format($value[columns][amount], 0.00, '.', ',');
    echo "</td><td><a class='woocommerce-button button' href='https://test.com/?a=print&token=". $pmToken ."&i=". base64_encode("PM-" + $value[columns][internalid][internalid]) ."' target='_new'>Print</a>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    }
    ?>
```

Im so new to PHP Im not sure how to grab the data
I assume in alot of other languages its just a case of

$someArray.transactions would be the way to do it, but I cant figure out how to get it in PHP

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert object into array, so you should use php function

$object = json_decode(json_encode($array), FALSE);

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your object is:

```
$obj = '{
"data":
{
"pages":10,
"current":1,
"token":"1234-1234-1234-1234",
"transactions":[{"id"}]
}
}';


$arr = (array)$obj;

var_dump($arr); //This will be displayed as array
```

Working example:
http://codepad.org/uCIB7kfh

Answer (score 0):

> Use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

In your case, put 
`$s = '{"key":"value"}'
$someArray = json_decode($s);`
before the for loop, you can then add 
`var_dump($someArray);` 
to view the structure and fetch the corresponding data value.